# Implicit parameters required

Tags: scala

I defined an union type like this :

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import reactivemongo.play.json._
import reactivemongo.play.json.collection.JSONCollection
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object Models {

sealed trait BiosChannel {
    val id : Int
    val label : String
    val samplingRate : Int
    val scaleFactor : Double
  }

case class CCWBiosChannel
    (
      id : Int,
      label : String,
      samplingRate : Int,
      scaleFactor : Double
    ) extends BiosChannel



case class NNBiosChannel
    (
      id : Int,
      label : String,
      samplingRate : Int,
      scaleFactor : Double,
      amplitude : Double,
      position : Option[String],
      localisation : Option[List[Double]]
    ) extends BiosChannel

  implicit val biosChannelReads = {
    val ccwBiosChannel = Json.reads[CCWBiosChannel]
    val nnBiosChannel = Json.reads[NNBiosChannel]
    __.read[CCWBiosChannel](ccwBiosChannel).map(x => x : BiosChannel) |
    __.read[NNBiosChannel](nnBiosChannel).map(x => x : BiosChannel)
  }

  implicit val biosChannelWrites = Writes[BiosChannel] {
    case ccwBiosChannel : CCWBiosChannel =>
      Json.writes[CCWBiosChannel].writes(ccwBiosChannel)
    case nnBiosChannel : NNBiosChannel =>
      Json.writes[NNBiosChannel].writes(nnBiosChannel)
  }
}
```

And then, I wrote some unit test in order to check if I can serialize and deserialize a CCWBiosChannel and NNBiosChannel. I tried to write a function taking a generic type T because I would like to reuse the following function :

```
import org.scalatest._
import play.api.libs.json._
import BiosModels._

class BiosModelsSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {  

def serializeAndDeserialize[T](implicit reads : Reads[T], writes : Writes[T]) =
    ((x : T) => Json.toJson(x)) andThen ((y) => y.validate[BiosRecord].get)
val ccwBiosChannels = List(CCWBiosChannel(0, "",-1,0.0, ChannelType.ECG, Units.mV, blocks))
val ccwBiosEvents = List(CCWBiosEvent(0L,0L,Some(""), CCWEventType.NOTWORN, CCWEventSource.mELEC))
val ccwBiosRecord = CCWBiosRecord("", "", 0L, 0L,1, ccwBiosChannels, Some(ccwBiosEvents))

 serializeAndDeserialize(ccwBiosChannel) // compilation error here
}
```

I get one error at the compilation :

```
not enough arguments for method serializeAndDeserialize: (implicit reads: play.api.libs.json.Reads[T], implicit writes: play.api.libs.json.Writes[T])T => com.bioserenity.core.data.BiosModels.BiosRecord.
[error] Unspecified value parameter writes.
[error]     serializeAndDeserialize(ccwBiosChannel)
```

The thing that I cannot understand is that I have implicit reads/writes defined for my case classes. Also, implicits parameters must be not required as in my error. So what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: As calling `.toJson` the `def serializeAndDeserializeBiosRecord` must declare the requirement to have an appropriate `Writes`. BTW your def would be much more readable with a complete definition, rather than using lambda.

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong code. I updated it.

Comment: There is no `Writes` available in the implicit scope of the caller of `serializeAndDeserialize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend setting an explicit type on your implicit reads and writes definition like so:

```
implicit val biosChannelReads: Reads[BiosChannel] = {
  val ccwBiosChannel = Json.reads[CCWBiosChannel]
  val nnBiosChannel = Json.reads[NNBiosChannel]
  __.read[CCWBiosChannel](ccwBiosChannel).map(x => x : BiosChannel) |
    __.read[NNBiosChannel](nnBiosChannel).map(x => x : BiosChannel)
}

implicit val biosChannelWrites: Writes[BiosChannel] = Writes[BiosChannel] {
  case ccwBiosChannel : CCWBiosChannel =>
    Json.writes[CCWBiosChannel].writes(ccwBiosChannel)
  case nnBiosChannel : NNBiosChannel =>
    Json.writes[NNBiosChannel].writes(nnBiosChannel)
}
```

And then modify the your serialize / deserialize method to look like the following:

```
def serializeAndDeserialize[T, V](x: T)(implicit reads : Reads[V], writes : Writes[T]): V = {
  Json.toJson(x).validate[V].get
}
```

Then you can call it in the following way (fill in the types as appropriate):

```
serializeAndDeserialize[List[<input type here>], List[<output type here>]](ccwBiosChannels)
```

Comment: Using two generic types make the thing works ! Thank you !